# regex - Parameter type mismatch when using regex_search function in C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, text

I am trying to run the example code for the `regex_search` function found in [the docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/).

**The code in their example is the following:**

```
// regex_search example
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("this subject has a submarine as a subsequence");
  std::smatch m;
  std::regex e ("\\b(sub)([^ ]*)");   // matches words beginning by "sub"

  std::cout << "Target sequence: " << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Regular expression: /\\b(sub)([^ ]*)/" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "The following matches and submatches were found:" << std::endl;

  while (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
    for (auto x:m) std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    s = m.suffix().str();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this code on my computer (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and using g++ compiler) I get the following warning on my IDE for the `m` parameter:
`Parameter type mismatch: Class 'std::smatch' is not compatible with class 'std::match_results<const char *, std::allocator<std::sub_match<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::const_iterator>>>'`

And this other one for the `s` parameter: `Parameter type mismatch: Types 'const char *' and 'std::string' are not compatible`.

**When I try to compile the code I get:**

```
./src/launcher.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./src/launcher.cpp:18:3: error: ‘smatch’ was not declared in this scope
   smatch m;
   ^
./src/launcher.cpp:18:3: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/regex:61:0,
                 from ./src/launcher.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/regex.h:1900:50: note:   ‘std::__cxx11::smatch’
   typedef match_results<string::const_iterator>  smatch;
                                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/regex.h:1900:50: note:   ‘std::__cxx11::smatch’
./src/launcher.cpp:19:3: error: ‘regex’ was not declared in this scope
   regex e ("\\b(sub)([^ ]*)");   // matches words beginning by "sub"
   ^
./src/launcher.cpp:19:3: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/regex:61:0,
                 from ./src/launcher.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/regex.h:786:32: note:   ‘std::__cxx11::regex’
   typedef basic_regex<char>    regex;
                                ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/regex.h:786:32: note:   ‘std::__cxx11::regex’
./src/launcher.cpp:25:26: error: ‘m’ was not declared in this scope
   while (regex_search (s,m,e)) {
                          ^
./src/launcher.cpp:25:28: error: ‘e’ was not declared in this scope
   while (regex_search (s,m,e)) {
                            ^
./src/launcher.cpp:26:17: error: unable to deduce ‘auto&&’ from ‘m’
     for (auto x:m) std::cout << x << " ";
                 ^
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'launcher.o' failed
make: *** [launcher.o] Error 1
```

I solved the problem with the `s` parameter by converting it to a c-string using the `c_str()` function. Nevertheless, I haven't been able to fix the problem with the `m` parameter.

I have tried to change the type of `m` to `match_results` (which is its template class) but errors persisted. I have also tried to change the type of `m` to the types suggested by the warning on my IDE, but problems persist.

I understand that the problem is that the type of `m` is not the type that the function is expecting but I don't know how to solve it.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

My main goal is to adapt that code to extract a certain string that contains a certain substring, so if anyone has any suggestions on how to do that, I'll be very thankful aswell.

Comment: Compiles [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdca6acb402d1e2c)

Comment: Im using c++11, it appears that that website uses c++14. Also, do you have any idea of why does it compile there and not on my machine?

Comment: What is the gcc version?

Comment: `g++ --version` returns the following: `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609`

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew I have tried 2 methods. Firstly, I use the following command: `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall`. After getting so many errors, I used the CLion IDE to run the code. Both methods have failed to compile.

Comment: Well, I have no issues when using 1) `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o myprog <FILE_PATH>`, 2) `./myprog`

Comment: That seems to work. What does `myprog` do? I'm sorry for so many questions. I'm just getting started with c++. I'm still having trouble to adapt that code to my own purposes, but that belongs to another question. If you add an answer to **this question**, I'll accept it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `myprog` is the program file name, `./myprog` will run the executable.

Comment: I found a duplicate for it, I will close. You may also use `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o myprog 1.cc && ./myprog` to compile the code and run with a one-liner.